# Python com a competência do mês anterior

Tags: python, datetime

Queria um código em python que, todos os mêses, quando o relatório for gerado, a o mês seja preenchido com o mês anterior e não o atual. No StackOverFlow em inglês encontrei algo semelhante, mas sem a timezone de Brasília, então adaptei para o trecho abaixo, mas caso alguém tenha um método com menos linhas de código, seria bom saber.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# ajustando timezone para Brasília
tz_Brasilia = pytz.timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
data = datetime.now(tz_Brasilia)

# coletando como int e subtraindo para depois, como str, preencher com zeros
year = data.strftime('%Y')
month = str(int(data.strftime('%m'))-1).zfill(2)
competencia = f'{year}-{month}'

print(competencia)
```

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3424899) tem algumas soluções que podem ajudar

Answer (score -1):

Se a ideia é só pegar o mês anterior, basta subtrair um do mês e, se for janeiro, subtrair um do ano, deixando o mês igual a 12. Basicamente o que foi feito aí, mas dependendo de uma biblioteca de terceiros.

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()  # 2024-03-28
month, year = (today.month-1, year) if today.month > 1 else (12, today.year-1)

print(f"{year}-{month:02}")  # 2024-02
```